# Get the StartUp Project of the current sln file on building

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Some of my projects have behavior based on the settings of the startup project. I.e. copy the resource to some other directory etc.

How can I get the reference to the startup project (the path to the folder would be also enough) on buildig of a project inside VS 2010?

Regards,
Andrey

Answer (score 0):

Go to TOOLS
[image: VS Tools]

Select OPTIONS

Then Start UP

[image: VS Start UP]

Also check that Detect when file is changed outside of environment.

[image]

You need to start every new project from a blank project. If a current project is open, there should be an option to close it before creating or opening another project. It's important not to mix up files from different projects.